# React Native Redux doesn't update array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

**ADD ITEM SCREEN**

```
export class additem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      price: "",
      category: "",
        };
  }

submitItem = (name, price, category) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("ItemList", {
      item: {
      name: name,
      price: price,
      category: category,
   }});
  };

render(){
return(


    <View>
       <TextInput onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}/>
       <TextInput onChangeText={(price) => this.setState({ price })}/>
       <TextInput onChangeText={(category) => this.setState({ category })}/>
       <Button onPress={() => this.submitItem(
                          this.state.name,
                          this.state.price,
                          this.state.category,
                          )}/>
    </View>
)}
```

**LIST ITEM SCREEN**

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

 class ItemList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemList:[],
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.route.params?.item) {
      props.dispatch({type:'ADD_ITEM'}); 
    }
    return null;
  }
  
  

  render() {
    
    return (

      <FlatList
            data={this.props.itemList}
            contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 , flexGrow: hp('20%')}}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <View> 
                  ///output from flatlist
                </View>
                )}/>
        );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(store){
  return{
      itemList: store.userState.itemList,
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemList);
```

**REDUX SCREEN REDUCERS**

```
import { USER_STATE_CHANGE } from "../constants";

const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  itemList: [],
};

export const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type){
      case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
        return {
          ...state,
          currentUser: action.currentUser,
        };
      case 'ADD_ITEM': 
      return{
        item: state.itemList,
      }
      default:
        return state
  }
  
};
```

Hello, I am learning `React-Redux` and I've come across a problem. The goal of the app is to add a grocery item from the Add Item Screen and once I submit it with the `Button`, it should send me to the Item List Page.

Once I get there I use a `static getDerivedStateFromProps` to check if the array was sent, and use Redux to update the global state in the Reducers Page, and at the end display the results in a `Flatlist`.

The problem is that when I run the code it prints the error `Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component`.

Comment: Which state update causes that error?

Comment: itemList, currentUser has always worked fine

Comment: There is no code that updates itemList. In your dispatch, you should send the item to the redux store. Also having dispatch in derived state might leads to an infinite loop. Instead of that, you should update redux from add item component

Comment: Another problem in your code is that you are overwriting the whole state in onChangeText. You should be doing something like this on all on change texts: `this.setState({ ...this.state, name:name })`

Answer (score 1):

You should dispatch an action from addItem file.

you can make two add a variable in store eg "loading" and just before dispatching the action "addItem" set that variable to true by calling another action
and after the item is successfully added make the loading variable false

and in the addItem component listen for the loading to be false after setting it to true and then navigate to the next screen

in your code the problem is that you are dispatching an action in getDerivedState method (that seems to be the problem)

or you can make POC on snack expo so we can have a better understanding
Thanks :)